# Programmatically delete parts of NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have an iOS app which connects to a server via OAuth 2.0. I get returned an access token in this form:

```
{accessToken="521515.ab6dc96.51dca3d53c4236d2d4f4460b151bc58d6ec91e14"}
```

And I store that in a NSString. The problem I am having is that I ONLY need the part which is in the quotation marks. How can I extract that?

**UPDATE**

Here us my code:

```
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth_instagram;
auth_instagram = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:@"Instagram" clientID:kMyClientID_instagram clientSecret:kMyClientSecret_instagram];

NSLog(@"%@", auth_instagram);
```

Printed in the Xcode console is:

```
GTMOAuth2Authentication 0xb2c0a80: {accessToken="541019.ab6dc96.51dc0d264d2d4f60b151bc8d6ec91e14"}
```

Comment: How is XCode connected here?..

Comment: Xcode is the IDE I am using to make my iOS App.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff yeah, but the question isn't reallt specific to Xcode just because it happens to be the IDE you are using. (tag removed)
The tag description even says so: "This tag should only be used for questions about Xcode itself, and not for general Mac or iOS programming topics"

Comment: Tell us how you get that data from OAuth (i.e. what class is it wrapped in).

Comment: How can an NSString be changed by other means than programmatically?

Comment: Well I'm using Google OAuth Consumer library for iOS. I have authenticated with a server which returned an access token. Now I need to use that access token to make a POST request, but the problem is the token string has more than just the code....

Comment: So wouldn't Google's API return the access token as an `AFOAuth1Token ` object?  If so, why is it now a formatted string?

Comment: It looks like you got json back: a dictionary with the key "accessToken". (sorry, I accidentally deleted the previous comment when I meant to edit it)

Comment: I believe it does. It is not actually a formatted string. But I need to use it in a URL which I am using to make a POST request.

Comment: I'm confused.  It's vital to know how you get this access token back from the API you are using.  If you can ask the API for it directly, then do so.  If it means parsing a JSON response, then do so.  What you don't want, however, is it in the form you currently have it.

Comment: `{accessToken="5215...1e14"}` looks like the NSLog output or description of an NSDictionary, not like JSON. So it seems that you already got a dictionary, which you somehow forced into a string.

Comment: @MartinR  Yes that is correct. I am forcing it into a string because I need to use that string for a URL in order to make a POST request. The problem is that now it is in a string, I need to delete part of the string.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff: Why can't you extract the token from the dictionary before it is converted to a string? E.g. `NSString *token = responseDict[@"accessToken"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read the class definition at http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/source/browse/trunk/Source/GTMOAuth2Authentication.h correctly, `GTMOAuth2Authentication` has a

```
@property (retain) NSString *accessToken;
```

so that you can just do

```
NSString *token = auth_instagram.accessToken;
```

to get the token as a string.

***Remark:*** Your output

```
{accessToken="521515.ab6dc96.51dca3d53c4236d2d4f4460b151bc58d6ec91e14"}
```

is the result of calling the `description` method of `GTMOAuth2Authentication`.
This is **not JSON**. JSON would look like

```
{ "accessToken" : "521515.ab6dc96.51dca3d53c4236d2d4f4460b151bc58d6ec91e14" }
```

Comment: Thank you sir!!!! Once again you have saved me from hours of not understanding what the problem was. Thank you for your superb example and explanation of what was wrong. For many hours I too was under the believe that this was JSON, but I was wrong. Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The right way would be to parse the whole string using the correct format/parser, in this case probably `NSJSONSerialization` and extract the value from the `accessToken` element.

```
NSDictionary *parsedData = [JSONObjectWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *value = parsedData[@"accessToken"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* components = [accessStr componentsSeparatedByString: "\""];
NSString* requiredStr = [components objectAtIndex: 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSDictionary *dic =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [YourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
//yourstring is the string in which u store and &e is just an NSError u can create urself like  NSError *e;

  NSString access_Token=[dic objectForKey:@"accessToken"];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you got there is valid JASON. Try the following:

```
NSDictionary *loginInfo = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[@"{accessToken=\"521515.ab6dc96.51dca3d53c4236d2d4f4460b151bc58d6ec91e14\"}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSString *aToken = [loginInfon objectForKey:@"accessToken"];
```